# Standard ML sum function

Tags: function, types, sml, ml

I have a problem in which I am asked for a function that sums all the elements in a given variable `x`. For instance, `sum([5,5,5])` should return 15.

My troubles come into play when I test the sum of a single integer like this: `sum(5)`

The function is supposed to be able to go back and fourth between single numbers and a list of numbers. I know that to do this, I need a datatype which has some `Int of int | Null | ...`

My question is how do I make the code below work for the test case `sum(5)`;

```
fun sum(x) = if x = nil
             then 0
             else hd(x) + sum(tl(x))

val result = sum([5,5]);
```

I think I need something like:

```
else if (int? x) then x
else hd(x) + sum(tl(x))
```

but when i do this with my datatypes i get clash of int vs int list.

Comment: With the data type you're suggesting, a test case would be something like `sum (Int 5)` or `sum Null`, not `sum [5,5,5]`. Please expand on what the function is supposed to do.

Comment: Well, the objective here is to convert a LISP function into ML. The lisp function not only works on lists, but also for a single atomic numeral value which is checked by (is number?). Apparently, referencing another response here this is impossible in standard ML. To reference both a single int and list. The sum([5,5,5]) already works as it is. needing sum(5) to return 5 is my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question quickly: That is not possible. As you correctly say, you need a datatype that allows you to hold either a single integer, or a list of integers. You could introduce such a type like:

```
datatype my_int = SingleInt of int | ManyInts of int list

fun sum (SingleInt i) = i
  | sum (ManyInts is) = foldl op+ 0 is
```

But this is really kind of silly, because if you think about it, the type `int list` can already hold a single integer or a list of integers (and even zero integers which, when it comes to sum, has a well-defined meaning). Thus, it does not make sense to extend your function beyond handling lists.

And regardless of whether you use a custom type or not, you will not have access to overloading, so being able to write either `sum 5` or `sum [5,5,5]` is not possible in Standard ML. In other functional languages, like Haskell, you can achieve this kind of overloading using type classes.

As a side note, try and use pattern matching rather than if-then-else. Your sum function would be:

```
fun sum [] = 0
  | sum (x::xs) = x + sum xs
```

Or making a tail-recursive version:

```
fun sum xs =
    let fun helper [] result = result
          | helper (x::xs) result = helper xs (x+result)
    in helper xs 0 end
```

Or simply using folding:

```
val sum = foldl op+ 0
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right it does seem redundant just that the code i'm trying to convert works in this manner for LISP, which I was told should be easily converted into ML. Seems like this is not the case.

Comment: Most Lisps aren't strongly typed, so they would allow for functions/macros that accept a variety of input (and even a variable number of arguments) where ML's type system is more restrictive.